# MODX проверить строку "дата" на валидность - 2018-10-07 01:10:21

Tags: строки, modx, datetime

Получаю переменную из базы, как проверить соответствие шаблону?
"Y-m-d H:i:s"

Comment: Добрый день не могли бы вы посмотреть мой вопрос так как мне пока нельзя спрашивать ! не грузиться ничего при нажатии на ответить ( http://energo.gov.kz/index.php?id=713
Tickets перестало работать ответить на комментарий

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function timeValidate($string)
{

    $year_regex = "[1-2][0-9]{3}";
    $month_regex = "((0[0-9])|(1[0-2]))";
    $day_regex = "(([0-2][0-9])|(3[0-1]))";

    $hour_regex = "(([0-1][0-9])|(2[0-4]))";
    $minute_regex = "(([0-5][0-9])|60)";
    $second_regex = "(([0-5][0-9])|60)";

    $regex = "~^$year_regex\-$month_regex\-$day_regex\s$hour_regex\:$minute_regex\:$second_regex$~";

    return preg_match($regex, $string);

}

$str1 = '2018-10-07 01:10:21';
$str2 = '2018-13-07 01:10:21';
$str3 = '2018-10-32 01:10:21';

var_dump(timeValidate($str1)); // true
var_dump(timeValidate($str2)); // false
var_dump(timeValidate($str3)); // false
```

Данная функция не учитывает, что в месяце может быть 28, 29, 30 и 31 день, то есть 31 февраля будет валидная дата. 
Так же рекомендую посмотреть в сторону функции strtotime

Comment: Спасибо, работает.

Comment: Только выводит почему-то
 int[1] int[0] int[0]
но это мелочи.

Comment: @Старший Доктор замените `var_dump(timeValidate($str1))` на `echo timeValidate($str1)` и не будет int[1] :)

Comment: @Сергей Ермаков вы считаете, что дата 2018-10-07 **99:99:99** может считаться валидной?

Comment: @skarb Я считаю, что вам нужно подробнее почитать о регулярках.  `([0-1][0-9])|(2[0-4])`

Comment: @Сергей Ермаков При чем здесь мои познания в регулярных выражениях? Вы дали ответ, в котором время 99:99:99 считается валидным

Comment: @skarb Отредактировал ответ, спасибо за замечание