# MODX синтаксис запроса where с вложенными условиями

Tags: запрос, modx, синтаксис

Есть строка

```
&where=`[{"Date_1:>":[[!currentDate]],
        "OR:Date_2:>":[[!currentDate]]}]`
```

то есть,

(условие1 OR условие2)

Как сделать (в плане синтаксиса написания запроса MODX )

((условие1 AND условие11) OR (условие2 AND условие22))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скрипт вашего варианта будет вызывать сниппет **currentDate** несколько раз. Не стоит так делать. Лучше используйте плейсхолдеры для однократного вызова. Пример сниппета currentDate

```
   $startDate = '18-09-2018';
   $endDate = '30-09-2018';

   $modx->setPlaceholders(
       array(
           'startDate' => $startDate, 
           'endDate' => $endDate
       ),
   'currentDate.');
```

После чего на странице вы сможете получать доступ к установленным значениям через **[[!+currentDate.startDate]]** и **[[!+currentDate.endDate]]**

В таком случае ответ на ваш вопрос будет таким:

```
    [[!currentDate]]

    [[pdoResources?
        &class  = ``
        &select = ``
        &sortby = `` 
        &where  = `Date_1 > '[[!+currentDate.startDate]]' AND Date_1 < '[[!+currentDate.endDate]]' OR Date_2 > '[[!+currentDate.startDate]]' AND Date_2 < '[[!+currentDate.endDate]]'`
    ]]
```

Comment: Спасибо, понял. И, раз уж вы здесь, помогите решить вторую часть вопроса.
Дело в том, что в приведенном мной примере условие1 и условие2 - это функция проверки даты на валидность. Мне ответили тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/889743/modx-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-2018-10-07-011021
Как вызвать её и вставить результат в строку?